# Start Downloading and Installing Android App if app is not installed

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am using deep linking by this code in manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="abc.in"
        android:pathPrefix="/"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

It is open to my app when app is installed on clicking of link on web page.

In this i want to implement two things-

1. **Open My app when i type url and click on Go.**

At moment app is not opened when i type url and click on go.App is being opened when i click on website any link.

2. **I want to start downloading of app if app is not installed .**

At this moment i am able to transfer to play store when app is not installed but downloading not started.

I want your help if these things can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Following google tutorial on [Enabling deep linking](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) they provide the next example

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos”
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
        -->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also note that starting from Android 11, there is a security update and you need to launch your app at least once before deep Links will work.

2. > At this moment I am able to transfer to play store when app is not

> installed but downloading not started.

Its the best you are going to get, the only place where your download could be start automatically is from the play store, and they want to keep it that way ;)

Comment: you mean that downloading can not be started automatically

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Yep. Not from play store any way.

Comment: ok but my another question is that when i open link in browser then first time app is not opened.when my website is opened and i click somewhere in mywebsite then my app is opened.can i open app at start when url is typed and pressed go

Comment: @AshishAgrawal yeah this is due to security, see my update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. scheme is https, and it doesn\t work with http
2. you have to type valid link to markets

for example to open app from website inside Google Play :

> Search :
>   https://market.android.com/search?q=pname:packagename
>
> Open Directly :
>   https://market.android.com/details?id=packagename

Comment: this is working but i want to start installation if app is not installed.
what type valid market link you are saying

Comment: watch it by your phone, markets, websites  linked markets,

Comment: please help me i am not getting i have to do that